# How to stop event propagation when checkbox input changes?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

## Description

I want to implement a table component with checkboxes.
The problem I'm having is that when I click a checkbox, table row and table cell catch click event which I want to avoid.
When I click a checkbox, I want only that checkbox react to the change event.

I tried `event.stopPropagation` method but it does not work. Somehow, before the checkbox catches the change event, table row and cell containing that checkbox react to the click event when I click the checkbox.

How can I achieve what I want? Please help me!!

## Code

```
<template>
  <table>
    <tr @click="trClick">
      <td @click="tdClick">
        <input @change="checkboxChange" type="checkbox">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  methods: {
    trClick() {
      console.log("tr - click");
    },
    tdClick() {
      console.log("td - click");
    },
    checkboxChange(e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
      console.log("checkbox - change");
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style>
table {
  background: #cccccc;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
input {
  cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
```

## Demo Links

### Vue.js Ver.

I want this Vue version work as I expect.
https://codesandbox.io/s/pjxzvj9jvm

### Vanilla JavaScript Ver.

I just tried the same thing in vanilla JavaScript just in order to investigate how event propagation in JavaScript works.
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xNxgeM?editors=1111

## Animation GIFs

### Vue.js Ver at codesandbox

[image]
When I click the checkbox, what I want to see in the console is only "checkbox - change".

### Vanilla JavaScript Ver at codepen

[image]

Comment: From your code, you just stop `change` event not `click` event. So this `<input @click='$event.stopPropagation()' @change="checkboxChange" type="checkbox">` should works.

Comment: Thank you!! I tried it and it works as I expect!!

Comment: @click.stop="" should do it on the input element, if it has a v-model then you dont need a @change event.

Answer (score 5):

There is a built in solution in Vue to stop event propagation. Just use the `@targetEvent.stop` notation:

```
<input @click.stop @change="checkboxChange" type="checkbox">
```

Comment: What version of Vue is this solution for? When I try this in 2.6.14, my `checkboxChange` handler never gets called. I'm using a vuetify 1.5.24 checkbox, but from looking at the source code I don't think that should matter, since the `@change` and `@click` properties are among those passed into the subcomponent by a spread operation.